# generate outputLink action from data base

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

I have many menus of outputLink and I generated them from data base mysql
like:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{loginAction.subMenusBeans.subMenusBeansList}" 
var="subMenusBeansList">
<ui:fragment rendered="#{menusBeansList.menuId == subMenusBeansList.menuId}" >   

<h:commandLink id="circlLink" value="#{subMenusBeansList.subMenuName}"  
action="{subMenusBeansList.subMenuLink}" />
</ui:fragment>
</ui:repeat>
```

I get value of action from database and set it to 'subMenusBeansList.subMenuLink'

**output:**

```
head quarter
main offices
offices
and so on..
```

when I click on any of above link

exception:
`action="#{subMenusBeansList.subMenuLink}":` Method not found:

I want to set action method name from database because I have many hyperlink and want to set all links action from data base and generate them to xhtml using ui:repeat but when i click on any of hyperlink's action generated from `#{subMenusBeansList.subMenuLink}'` throw exception

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /template/
    templateslider.xhtml @36,135 action="#{subMenusBeansList.subMenuLink}":
 Method not found: com.ss.managedbeans.SubMenusBeans@552edddd.subMenuLink()
```

Comment: So, the `#{subMenusBeansList.subMenuLink}` is supposed to be a getter which returns a navigation outcome? Why don't you just use a `<h:link>` instead of `<h:commandLink>`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running in to here is that `<h:outputLink action="XXXX">` actually expects a MethodExpression, which is why it is not attempting to resolve the getter for your property, "subMenuLink."

What you probably want is, as BalusC suggested, to use an ` instead. This attribute expects a ValueExpression, and should be able to resolve your property and its getter.